# Returning from event.Click, event.Resize and eventDrop causes NaN appearing everywhere when moving to a different view or calendar page

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I am using PHP to work with JQuery and Javascript and integrating fullcalendar.

I am happily viewing the calendar with events over months and weeks. I am also happily creating and editing events in fullcalendar by using event.Click, event.Resize and eventDrop.

However, when I return from the edit and then try to change the month/week etc, I just get NaN everywhere I expect to see days and so on. The update is done on an overlaid div containing an iframe. The script in the iframe calls a javascript function to close the div and refreshes the calendar using reFetchEvents. The original page is redisplayed okay, but when navigating to another part of the calendar I see the effect described.

Relevant Snippet from calendar display script

```
function close_upd(){  
/* called by update script in iframe after user hits submit/cancel */  
    $("#update").dialog('close');  
    $("#calendar").fullCalendar('refetchEvents');  
}  
$(document).ready(function(){  
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({  
        theme: true,  
        defaultView: '<?=$view;?>',  
        firstHour: 8,  
        header: {  
            left: 'prev,next today',  
        center: 'title',  
         right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
      },
      selectable: true,  
      selectHelper: true,  
      select: function(startdate, enddate, allDay, jsEvent, view) {  
         window.scrollTo(0,0);  
         var sd = Date.parse(startdate);  
         var ed = Date.parse(enddate);  
         $("#update").html("CALLS IFRAME");  
         $("#update").dialog('open');  
      },  
      editable: true,  
      eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {  
         window.scrollTo(0,0);  
         var sd = Date.parse(calEvent.start);  
         var ed = Date.parse(calEvent.end);  
         $("#update").html("CALLS IFRAME");  
         $("#update").dialog('open');  
      },  
      eventResize: function(calEvent,dayDelta,minuteDelta,revetFunc) {  
         var sd = Date.parse(calEvent.start);  
         var ed = Date.parse(calEvent.end);  
         $.post('./event_update2.php',{'allday':'false', 'event':calEvent.id, 'start':sd,'end':ed}, function(response){  
            if(response.length > 0){  
               alert(response);  
               revertFunc();  
            }  
         });  
      },  
      eventDrop: function(calEvent,dayDelta,minuteDelta,allDay,revetFunc) {  
         var sd = Date.parse(calEvent.start);  
         var ed = Date.parse(calEvent.end);  
         $.post('./event_update2.php',{'allday':allDay, 'event':calEvent.id, 'start':sd, 'end':ed}, function(response){  
            if(response.length > 0){  
               alert(response);  
               revertFunc();  
            }  
         });  
      },  
      eventMouseover: function( event, jsEvent, view ) {  
         var showdatea = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.start,"dS MMM yyyy");  
         var showdateb = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.start,"hh:mm");  
         showToolTip(jsEvent,event.title+" "+showdatea+" Starts At "+showdateb+" "+event.desc);  
      },  
      eventMouseout: function( event, jsEvent, view ) {  
         hideToolTip();  
      },  
      events: './event_find.php?from=PP'  
   });  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What does Firebug tell you? Is everything fetched correctly from the server? First render the calendar the first time you'd be able to inspect what was returned in the GET of `event_find.php?from=PP`. So the second time, after closing the edit overlay, does the server respond with the same GET data (plus the new edit change)?

After that, when you click prev/next does it now load different data in the GETs?

Knowing this will be a good start to understanding what's going on.